# Axios - how to properly set cookies with same-site=None in modern browser

Tags: reactjs, cookies, axios, session-cookies, setcookie

The scenario is that I post to the backend API and then get back the session ID, and after that, I can put it in browser cookie for another API request.

I have created an axios instance as following

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
      baseURL: "https://example.com",
      timeout: 120000,
      withCredentials: true,
      credentials: "include",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        accept: "application/json",
      },
    });


axiosInstance
      .post("/login-and-get-session", null, {
        params: {
         ... some data
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("response post = ", res);
        axiosInstance
          .get("/some-get-url", {
            params: {
              ... some data           
            },
          })
          .then((res) => {
            console.log("response get = ", res);
          });
      });
```

I have searched many articles that say with `withCredentials: true`, the browser will automatically set cookies for us.

but I get the following message from the browser:

```
This Set-Cookie didn't specify a "SameSite" attribute and was default to "SameSite=Lax" .... The Set-cookie had to have been set with "Same Site=None" to enable cross-site usage.
```

and then I tried like

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
      baseURL: "https://example.com",
      timeout: 120000,
      withCredentials: true,
      credentials: "include",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        accept: "application/json",
         "Set-Cookie":"SameSite=None; Secure",
      },
    });


axiosInstance
      .post("/someurl", null, {
        params: {
         ... some data
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("response post = ", res);
        axiosInstance
          .get("/some-other-url", {
            params: {
              ... some data           
            },
          })
          .then((res) => {
            console.log("response get = ", res);
          });
      });
```

or

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
      baseURL: "https://example.com",
      timeout: 120000,
      withCredentials: true,
      credentials: "include",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        accept: "application/json",
      },
    });


axiosInstance
      .post("/someurl", null, {
        params: {
         ... some data
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("response post = ", res);
        axiosInstance
          .get("/some-other-url", {
            params: {
              ... some data           
            },
            header: {
              "Set-Cookie": `JSESSIONID=${res.sessionId} SameSite=None; Secure`,
            }
          })
          .then((res) => {
            console.log("response get = ", res);
          });
      });
```

all are no use.

how to properly set cookies in axios for modern browsers?